# File helpers only returning one row of data

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am using FileHelpers to load into a class from a csv but its only pulling back one record for some reason.

```
public void LoadPumpData(string Filename)
{
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(FuelPumpData));
        //read the CSV file into your object Arrary
        var productSales = (FuelPumpData[])engine.ReadFile(Filename);


        if (productSales.Any())
        {
            //process your records as per your requirements
            foreach (var sales in productSales)
            {
                string carCodeNumber = GetCustomerCodeByVechicleTag(sales.VechicleTagNo);
                CreateInvoice(carCodeNumber, double.Parse(sales.FuelQty), double.Parse(sales.FuelValue));

            }
        }

 }
```

This is my class

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
[IgnoreFirst()]

public class FuelPumpData
{
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]

    public int Date { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.OptionalForRead)]

    public int Time { get; set; }
    public string SystemGroup1 { get; set; }
    public string SystemGroup3 { get; set; }
    public string VechicleTagNo { get; set; }
    public string SystemGroup2 { get; set; }
    public string SystemGroup4 { get; set; }
    public string FuelQty { get; set; }
    public string FuelValue { get; set; }
    public string FuelType { get; set; }
}
```

I thought read field and passing it a array of my class would allow all the rows to be read but its only returning the first row ?.

**Edit 2** 
Create invoice routine

```
 public void CreateInvoice(string customerCode, double fuelQty, double price)
 {
        try
        {
            SAPbobsCOM.Documents oInvoice = company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oInvoices);

            oInvoice.DocDate = DateTime.Now;
            oInvoice.CardCode = customerCode;

            oInvoice.Lines.ItemDescription="David Test";
            oInvoice.Lines.ItemCode = "DSL";
            oInvoice.Lines.Quantity = fuelQty;
            oInvoice.Lines.LineTotal = price;
            oInvoice.Lines.Add();



            int addInvoice = oInvoice.Add();

            if (addInvoice < 0 )
            {
                Console.Write("Error:" + company.GetLastErrorDescription());

            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {


        }

    }
```

The create invoice routine creates an invoice within the sap business one product it does not overwrite the product sales.

Edit 3 
Showing My Debugging

[image]

CSV Record to show to lines of data

```
"011018","0020","D SAYERS","SYSTEM DEFAULT",   5680,"20101","06009",35.64  ,               52.14,"DSL"
"011018","0438","SYSTEM DEFAULT","DECLAN MCDERMOTT",   5839,"SYSTEM DEFAULT","14502",36.52  ,               53.43,"DSL"
```

Comment: Are you certain it's only reading in one row (meaning you've looked at the array in the debugger)? Is `CreateInvoice` overwriting the previous output when it runs?

Comment: How many rows have your file ? You can use the generic version to avoid casting
 var engine = new FileHelperEngine<FuelPumpData>();
 var productSales = engine.ReadFile(Filename);

Comment: @MarcosMeli please see above added createivnocie routine

Comment: @DStanley please see above edit

Comment: How **exactly** are you verifying that it only reads one row.

Comment: By debugging my code and seeing that only one item was in the productsales[]

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen please see above edits thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else my issue was I had ignore first  on thinking I was going get header information in the file when I am not.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
[IgnoreFirst()]
```

One I removed IgnoreFirst the file was detetected correctly with the right information.